# Django and haystack with whoosh

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I've set up django with haystack but im having a few problems.

I have a line in my search_indexes.py that says

```
body = indexes.TextField(model_attr='body')
```

This corresponds to the line in my models.py that says

```
body = models.TextField()
```

Im getting an error when i try and run rebuild_index

```
body = indexes.TextField(model_attr='body')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TextField'
```

If i comment out the line in search_indexes.py it adds my documents to the index. How can i fix this?

I have seven videos named "test vid 1" through to "test vid 7". When i search "test" or "vid" they all show up, thats fine. However when i search "6" nothing shows up and when i search "test vid 6" they all show up. It seems like haystack not taking into account the number, any idea why this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error mean `TextField` does not exists in `indexes`.

Use `indexes.CharField`.

Comment: Sorry i meant body (textfield). 
Im importing indexes in search_indexes.py with the line
"from haystack import indexes". thanks

Comment: I can't as my model is already designed and populated. Does haystack not work with textfields then? Any way around this?

Comment: django-haystack has only CharField (you can use it to store models.TextField). Replace ``body = indexes.TextField(model_attr='body')`` with ``body = indexes.CharField(model_attr='body')``